# Format name from input using string slicing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an assignment that I need help with.

In my program, I am prompting users to enter their fullname in first, middle, and last name order.

```
fullname = input("Enter your full name in first, middle, and last name order: ")
```

From the fullname entered, I need to pull off the first character of the first name and pull off the last name into separate variables, and I am not sure how to proceed.

I cannot use the split function for this. Instead, I must use the String slicing technique.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the first inital by slicing the string at index 0 since this will be the first char. for the last name you can do an rfind on the string to find the first space from the right side of the string. Then slice from the first char after that to the end of the string for the last name

```py
fullname = input("Enter your full name in first, middle, and last name order: ")
print(f"{fullname[0]} {fullname[fullname.rfind(' ')+1:]}")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Enter your full name in first, middle, and last name order: foo bar baz
f baz
```

Comment: Thanks! This is super helpful! But how do I pull the middle initial if/when there is one?